# Vlookup then return a different row in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm struggling to figure out how to get sheets to first look up the location of a key value and then look up which of the sub values it should take.  Best would be to include an example, which:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pL62W7pSImMlTdnU3RMV4VDK3KIuNBT8l3VxClLGTd4/edit?usp=sharing

What I'm hoping to achieve is that the values for item 1, when selected, auto fill in the correct gear builder fields.

Any advice on this is hugely appreciated.

Comment: So I decided the easiest solution was to have multiple rows with the item 1 + the additional values.  I've put what I've done in the example sheet.  It's not pretty and I do believe there would be another, more elegant way about this, so please feel free to share should you know it :)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: have changed that now.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 IF(F4:F12<>"", VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A12), 
 IF(G4:G12<>"", {ROW(A4:A12), G4:G12&"♦"}), 2, 1), )&F4:F12, {
 IF(B4:B12<>"", VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A12), 
 IF(A4:A12<>"", {ROW(A4:A12), A4:A12&"♦"}), 2, 1), )&B4:B12, C4:C12}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]